# AndEngine: update handler on sprite

Tags: android, andengine

I am newbie to and-engine since working with it from fast two weeks. I am developing the ball game,My requirement as follows that when the ball touches to ground body for second time it should get destroy. I tried with update handler on ball sprite, its working fine when count reaches 2(I explicitly call remove logic).At the time it touches to ground body, I am destructing the ball body with the help of count in handler on Update(). Unfortunately for the first time also(count reaches 2 at first collision) body is getting destroyed. Above scenario is repeated often, worked with contact listener but no change.Any help would be appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
Shape path = new Rectangle(ballSprite.getX(),ballSprite.getY(), 10, 10);
if (ballCount <= 2) {
                mScene.attachChild(path);
                pathCoordinates.add(path);
                dumpPathCoordinates.add(path);
            }
            if (ballSprite.collidesWith(ground)) {
                ballCount++;
                if (ballSprite.collidesWith(ground) && ballCount == 2) {
                    removePath();
                    removeBall(ballSprite);
                    addFace(10, 10);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code. It will make the problem easier to understand.

Comment: @JohnEye i have posted the code over here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the first touch lasts longer than one engine iteration? If so, you need to allow the ball removal only if this sequence occurs
`touching->not touching->touching`.
So far the ball is removed even if the sequence is
`touching->still touching`.

Comment: Thanks for your response John, but it behaves different for each engine iteration, while tracking in log cat for first touch count gets incremented and for second time on wards it gets incremented twice. For third iteration it may or may not increment twice....it goes on like that. Taking much time to analyze the behavior. But of no use what can be the alternatives?

Comment: I think what you described is still consistent with what I said - the touch can last for more than one iteration thus the counter is incremented more than once per touch. If you add a condition that next touch must be preceded by at least one iteration without touching, the counter should work correctly regardless of how many iteration single touch lasts.

Comment: OK. onUpdate() gets called every time the screen refreshes. Now let's see what happens as the ball approaches the ground. Step 1: the ball is just above the ground. Step 2: The ball starts touching the ground and the counter is incremented. Step 3: The ball is still touching the ground and the counter is incremented for the second time. Step 4: The ball stopped touching the ground. Your problem lies in Step 3 - although the ball only touched the ground once, it took two steps until it got above ground. continued...

Comment: Therefore, you need to check whether the ball spent at least one step above ground since the last incrementation of the counter and not increment it if it hasn't.

Comment: Thanks John, I got it by implementing logic, actually i don't know onUpdate() gets called every screen refresh.